# Comparing 2 CSV files & Outut differences to a CSV or Excel File

Tags: excel, csv

There're 2 CSV files and i want to compare the contents of them and output it to another CSV or XLS file.

CSV file 1

```
normal, vector, x-axis, y-axis, factor
1552, 8743, 332, 2355, 99.03
8800055, 322, 180, 443222, 555.005
223, 44553, 88553, 88993, 100.004
```

CSV file 2

```
normal, vector, x-axis, y-axis, factor
1552, 8743, 223, 2355, 99.03
8800055, 322, 180, 443222, 200.005
223, 44553, 88553, 1000, 100.004
```

As you see above the differences between the 2 are in 1st row x-axis, 2nd row factor and 3rd row y-axis.

So basically am looking for a comparison and output that to a 3rd csv or xls file like this,

```
normal, vector, x-axis, y-axis, factor
0, 0, 1, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 1
0, 0, 0, 1, 0
```

Basically 0's meaning no difference and 1's meaning there's difference.

Right now, am using a comparison tool like Beyond Compare or something to do this comparison.

Is there a way i can do this in Excel or something and then output the result as shown above?

Comment: Open each csv into a different worksheet then use arrays to loop through the values and generate a comparison matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the two csv files as sheets and then use a third sheet to show the difference "flag" as

B1:

```
=IF('Sheet 1'!B1='Sheet 2'!B1,0,1)
```

And fill the sheet with that formula.

If you want to leave blanks blank (i.e., only flag cells that have values), then use another IF() as a wrapper:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK('Sheet 1'!B1),ISBLANK('Sheet 2'!B1)),'',IF('Sheet 1'!B1='Sheet 2'!B1,0,1))
```

Then you can export that sheet as a csv.

Comment: is this case sensitive?

Comment: Excel is case sensitive, yes. Map the cell values to uppercase when comparing them if you want case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use VBA to create macros.

Here's a code snippet to compare two sheets and write the output to a new sheet:

```
Sub NoMatches() 'Excel vba to remove duplicates.
Dim dic As Object
Dim ar As Variant
Dim ar1 As Variant
Dim var As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

Set dic=Createobject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dic.CompareMode=1
ar=Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
var=Sheet2.Range("A2", Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
ReDim ar1(1 To UBound(var), 1 To 1)

'Loop through ar and add to Dictionary.
For i=1 To UBound(ar)
If Not dic.exists(ar(i, 1)) Then
dic.Add ar(i, 1), ar(i, 1)
End If
Next i

'Identify non Matches
For i=1 To UBound(var)
If Not dic.exists(var(i, 1)) Then
n=n + 1
ar1(n, 1)=var(i, 1)
End If
Next i

'Output Results Remove any Duplication
Sheet3.Range("E2:E" & UBound(var)).Value=ar1
Range("E2:E" & UBound(var)).RemoveDuplicates 1
End Sub
```

here is the link: 
https://www.thesmallman.com/compare-two-worksheets